# Implementing singly linked list methods.

Tags: java, methods, singly-linked-list

I've got classes (interface, instansiable and methods) to implement a singly linked list. The methods include add, remove, isEmpty(), printList() and size().

I'm just curious now, how could I implement these in my main class. I've started with:

```
SLLInterface si = new SLList();
```

Where SLList is a class which implements the interface methods. 
Now, if I wanted to add a node into the SLL, where the add method has two parameters:

```
public void add(Object theElement, int index);
```

How could this be done? I have tried:

```
SLLInterface si = new SLList();
si.add(Object x, index 0);
```

And other variations, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You'll get better results if you post your SLLInterface and SLList code.  Should work; what do you see?

Comment: `si.add(x, 0);` of course you should declare `x` first

Comment: What do you mean "can't get it to work"? What happens?

Comment: You have to make an object with the `new` keyword like you did with  `new SLList();` just saying `Object x` won't make anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should look like this:

```
SLLInterface si = new SLList();
Object x = new Object();
int index = 0;
si.add(x, index);
```

You're obviously learning, but you'd benefit from studying the `java.util.List` interface and implementing that as a singly-linked list.  Your design could be improved by studying what Joshua Bloch did.

Answer (score 0):

you may cross-reference your implementation of Linked list (if any) [with this one](http://www.sourcetricks.com/2008/07/c-singly-linked-lists.html)